# Updating <li> class within a <ul> element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update the class of all children elements of a ul element. Here is my code:

```
 $('#quoteLog').find('ul').click( function(event){
            if (this == event.target) {
                $(this).children().toggleClass('details-shown');
            }
            return false;
        })
                .children().addClass('details-hidden');
```

I have been messing around with the find value without much luck. This should find every ul element within a dev element with id=quotelog and add the details-hidden class to the li elements in the ul and change them to details-shown when the targeted ul element is clicked.

The html for this section looks like the following:

```
<div id="quoteLog">
    <ul class="quote"> Some name
        <li>detail about quote</li>
        <li>some other detail</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="quote"> Some other name...</ul>
    ...
```

Fairly new to JQuery and am having the problem with the click event being triggered or even the class being added to the li elements at all. Any help or a direction someone could point me to would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery supports CSS style selectors, so no need of `.find()` in this case. You can make it much cleaner - http://jsfiddle.net/f4njs/1/

```
$('#quoteLog ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('details-shown');
});
​
```

Comment: This is excellent. I try to stay away from <div> the best I can so instead I did $('#quoteLog ul').click(function() { $(this).children('li').slideToggle(300). Also I didn't know that the display had to be set to none at first and I think that might have been giving me problems. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#quoteLog').find('ul').click( function(event){
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).children().toggleClass('details-shown');
        }
        return false;
    })
```

This code will return the "UL" elements per default, not the QuoteLog element. Therefore, it is important that you exclude your `.Children` code and add the class first.

Try this resulting code (note how `.Children` is removed):

```
$('#quoteLog').addClass('details-hidden').find('ul').click( function(event){
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).children().toggleClass('details-shown');
        }
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: Still no luck. This doesn't add the class to the li elements. Hmm...does it make a difference that the li elements are added during the $(document).ready part of the javascript?

Answer (score 1):

why you would change even li, you can change only the class of the parent also ul and this class will interact with the childs li like:

```
$('#quoteLog ul').click( function(event){
  $(this).toggleClass('details-shown');
});


ul.details-shown li {
     /* do */
}
```

more efficient, because didn't iterate over each li, let css do this job

Answer (score 0):

I would associate the event to the single LI elements and not to the UL...

```
$('#quoteLog').find('ul li').click(function(event){
                $(this).toggleClass('details-shown');
})
```

Much cleaner IMHO: with this code you're telling: on every item of the list, on click, toggle the shown class. Not sure of what you're trying to achieve with the hidden class, but if you want to add it anyway (click or not) you can add it after the toggleClass() instruction.

```
$('#quoteLog').find('ul li').click(function(event){
                $(this).toggleClass('details-shown').addClass('details-hidden');
})
```

Comment: I am trying to make an expandable list and have the ul element be the specific part to be clicked on. So once the ul element is clicked it will display the information and then when clicked again will hide the information. Perhaps instead of doing this through css changes I should be using the .hide() from JQuery?

Comment: Actually what I am wanting won't work the way I'm describing. I will need to make the first li element be unique and allow this. SO I will just have each li element be the .click like you suggest.

Comment: Yep, you should use toggle() or slideDown()-like stuff :)

Comment: Ok. It's weird that the above code isn't even adding the class to the li elements. Maybe this doesn't work the way you described but the toggle/slideDown will. I guess it is more testing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need to do it with another way like:

`$('#quoteLog ul').each(function(){`

$(this).click(function({
$(this).children().each(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('details-shown');
});
}));
});